# How do I delegate NTLM authentication to a router?

Tags: networking, router, proxy, ntlm

I have credentials for NTLM in a business environment. I operate a router within that environment which passes the LAN network (via NAT) to a personal wifi network as my laptop and smartphone do not support LAN connections.

Right now both the laptop and smartphone need to authenticate via NTLM. Is it possible for me to set my router (a Linux embedded system) up to transparently proxy the NTLM LAN connection such that both laptop and smartphone do not need to set proxy settings?

Comment: There's over a dozen protocols which use NTLM. Are you talking about a HTTP proxy with NTLM auth, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. A HTTP proxy which uses NTLM auth to control access to the WWW, such that all devices connected must provide the right NTLM auth.